# Book I read years ago about 2-dimensional space encroaching on our own and slowly encompassing everything

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for the title of a book I read years ago about 2-dimensional space encroaching on our own and slowly encompassing everything. I remember one scene about a fleet of ships attempting to flee the 2-dimensional 'wall'.

Comment: Paper covers rock.

Answer (score 29):

This could be *Death's End*, by Liu Cixin, of the *Remembrance of Earth's Past* series.

The 2D space attack occurs in the book's "Bunker Era" and the attack is described by Wikipedia's article on the book:

> ...the weapon is revealed to be a spacetime anomaly that causes the third dimension to collapse into the second; humanity has no defense against this and will be rendered extinct within days as the effect spreads across the solar system... The only way to survive is either to flee at light speed, or find a way to live in the 2D plane; neither appears a realistic possibility.
>
> ...They watch from Pluto as the sun and the rest of the planets are pulled into the second dimension and flattened. As the collapse approaches Pluto, Luo Ji then reveals that their ship is equipped with humanity's only lightspeed drive, built in secret by Wade's associates after his death. He instructs them to escape the solar system while he stays behind. They set a course for DX3906 and escape ahead of the collapse wave, which pulls in Pluto and all the remaining human ships that were attempting to flee at sublight speeds, ending human civilization.
>
> Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death%27s_End#Bunker_Era

Comment: Not necessarily a relevant comment, but the physics in this quote is really annoying. If the transformation is happening at the speed of light then you won't be able to watch it happening, because it will reach you at exactly the same time the light does.

Comment: That quote is saying that you need an escape velocity of the speed of light, not that the expansion is happening at the speed of light.

Comment: @CharlieB makes no sense still, why would you need to escape something at the speed of light when it's moving slower?

Comment: @N.Virgo The transformation doesn't occur at the speed of light.

Comment: @Arsenal There's a lot more going on on the book than can be described in comments or even in an answer. For example, the speed of light is locally (and permanently) decreased in some locations of the universe. I'm not saying the physics makes sense but it's more complicated. You'd need to read the book.

Comment: @Arsenal Because you have no way to move at a speed between the minimal escape velocity and the speed of light? Or, more likely, no way to accelerate to the minimal escape velocity fast enough to outrun whatever you are fleeing from other than some technology that allows FTL travel without a major running start.

Comment: @Null okay then. I guess I'm not going to, but if it makes sense inside the book then it's okay.

Comment: Thanks a million @Null, you're absolutely right. That's the book I was looking for

Comment: @DeanAndrewWilliams Happy to help. Please consider [accepting this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as acceptance helps us determine that the question has been satisfactorily answered, link questions about the same story, etc.

Comment: Great. I read The Three-Body Problem and loved it. Then I learned with great surprise it was a trilogy. I resolved not to read books 2 and 3 because I suspected they would be terrible in comparison to the first. Several friends of mine read book 2 and told me they were loving it, but I held on and still did not read it. Then one of my favourite sf authors wrote that they loved book 2, so finally I gave in and read it. And. It. Sucked. Why did Liu Cixin even write this. So I resolved not to read book 3. And now your answer is cracking my resolve. Book 3 sounds a lot more cool than book 2.

Comment: @Stef Book 2 was the worst of the trilogy. I felt it could have been cut down considerably. Book 3 was awesome (as was book 1), and I have a hard time deciding whether 1 or 3 was better. Book 1 and 3 were so good I read them twice, which is unusual for me as I have such a long queue of new books I want to read.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to give book 3 a chance then, thank you for the advice. In exchange let me recommend a book as well: "Geometry for ocelots" by Exurb1a. One of the main concepts is that humanity has found a way to access 4d geometrical space, which has a ton of really cool consequences; but our brains can't naturally handle the geometry, so we need to take a drug to attain a state of "enlightenment" before we can safely use it.

Comment: @Stef Thanks for the recommendation, I'll check it out! *Death's End* does include a very similar section in which humans encounter four spatial dimensions and have trouble navigating it since we are accustomed to three.

Comment: Strange, I thought book two was the best of the three. So many interesting ideas.

Comment: @DeanAndrewWilliams If you're happy with this answer, don't forget to mark the answer as Accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Yeah, I thought book 3 was the worst one. It kind of reminded me of the last (or second to last, technically) Hitchhiker's book, which was much darker and meaner than the rest of the series.

Answer (score 8):

I'm reminded of Greg Egan's *[Schild's Ladder](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/156780)*, in which the universe is collapsing into a different state. The collapse is expanding spherically outwards (at a speed of *c*/2), consuming our universe, and people flee in front of it mostly my uploading their minds and transmitting them to other star systems.

> Twenty thousand years into the future, an experiment in quantum
> physics has had a catastrophic result, creating an enormous, rapidly
> expanding vacuum that devours everything it comes in contact with. Now
> humans must confront this deadly expansion. Tchicaya, aboard a
> starship trawling the border of the vacuum, has allied himself with
> the Yielders-- those determined to study the vacuum while allowing it
> to grow unchecked. But when his fiery first love, Mariama, reenters
> his life on the side of the Preservationists-- those working to halt
> and destroy the vacuum-- Tchicaya finds himself struggling with an
> inner turmoil he has known since childhood.
>
> However, in the center of the vacuum, something is developing that
> neither Tchicaya and the Yielders nor Mariama and the Preservationists
> could ever have imagined possible: life.

Though in this book there's no fleet of ships IIRC, there's a research ship/station keeping pace with the expanding wall, where a lot of the book's action happens.